# Forcing GCC to put specific statements in a specific section

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, llvm

I know that a compiler (at least GCC) can be forced to place specific functions in specific sections.

For example, consider the function foo.

```
int foo(int a, int b, int c);
```

By rewriting as follows, the compiler generates an executable ELF binary with the function placed in the output section `.custom`. (This also forces non-in-lining, because I need those functions to be called from their specific memory positions instead of just being replicated by the compiler.)

```
#define CUSTOMIZE    __attribute__((__section__(".custom"))) __attribute__ ((noinline))
int  CUSTOMIZE  foo(int a, int b, int c);
```

So my question is, is it possible to do so automatically for specific statements or blocks inside a function?

Obviously one way to do that is to just extract those parts (let's say the for loop for example, or the statement 3) and put them in specific functions, but this is too much surgery and doesn't scale for me. Any ideas?

```
int foo(int a, int b, int c)
{
   // Statement 1
   // Statement 2
   // Statement 3

   // For Loop Block
   for ( ... )
   {
       // For loop body
   }

   return some_value;
}
```

---

### EDIT

What I'm looking for is something equivalent to the following. Where the `For` loop is isolated in a separate function, that I can place in my custom section now.

I hope my intent is clearer now. My objective is just to know if there is a way to do that automatically by the compiler without extracting those parts manually (plus I also have to manage the arguments ...etc. long story short, too much surgery).

```
int CUSTOMIZE my_isolated_for_loop( some_arguments_here )
{
   // Place my for loop here, with the correct
   // For Loop Block
   for ( ... )
   {
       // For loop body
   }
   return result
}

int foo(int a, int b, int c)
{
   // Statement 1
   // Statement 2
   // Statement 3

   intermediate_result = my_isolated_for_loop( some_arguments_here )

   return some_value;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386992). Why exactly do you want to do this?

Comment: How would that even work?  Are you expecting the code preceding the relocated block to jump to it, and then jump back at the end?  That's a function call in all but name.

Comment: Following Paul's point, I'm skeptical that the compiler would be able to automatically extract a function and properly carry through all the state that code depends on. Jetbrains does a decent job of that in refactoring tools, but I wouldn't expect such in a compiler, let alone one that guarantees a perfect result.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Actually I need some parts of my application to fall in a particular specific section (for instrumentation purposes using a simulator I made.)

Comment: @PaulSanders I agree it's a function call but I kind of want those parts either to be extracted automatically to a new function for example ..

Comment: You want the compiler to refactor your code for you, in a way that's so complicated you can't even figure out how you'd do it yourself?

Comment: @chris If we forget extraction as a function for a moment, is there another approach to have a code placed in a section other than isolating it in a function?

Comment: Well, consult the gcc documentation, but I'll eat my hat if there is.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica As I tried to express (sorry for my bad english): That function isolating stuff I talked about (which represents my `Y` problem) is just my naive non-expert (and probably the only?) way to put some code in a specific position (which is originally my `X` problem).

Comment: @noureddine-as, I don't see how. The code you run in that section needs to know where to return to, so that's one part of regular functions. The code would also need the state of registers and the stack pointer saved in order to ensure no calling code is corrupted. That's the other main part of functions. At that point, I'm content to say that whatever solution there is to putting executable code in that section will look a lot like a function, even if there are some differences in the end. If the code you place there is non-executable, that's a different story.

Comment: It sounds like you want a lambda (when in C++), but I’m not sure those can be put in different sections.

Comment: You might be able to write an LLVM pass that identifies the functions and adds the section metadata. That is to say, you definitely can add the metadata, you might be able to write the pass. If you can write the pass it'll be simple (<50 lines plus the code to identify the appropriate spots).